# Queries regarding Mailkit

Tags: mailkit

I have a requirement where I need to download mails from mailbox, I have below queries

1. Is there any option to download bulk mails using ImapClient
2. How many concurrent connections I can open to a mailbox using ImapClient

Comment: My requirement is to download around 40k mails in an hour

Answer (score 0):

1. MailKit's ImapFolder class has some [GetStreams()](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/Overload_MailKit_Net_Imap_ImapFolder_GetStreams.htm) and [GetStreamsAsync()](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/Overload_MailKit_Net_Imap_ImapFolder_GetStreamsAsync.htm) APIs that you might find useful. Obviously, these APIs present the downloaded messages as System.IO.Stream instead of MimeMessage, but if you are bulk downloading messages, you probably don't intend to use them as MimeMessages anyway (you probably just want to dump them into files).
2. Each ImapClient only supports a single connection. That said, if you want multiple concurrent connections, there's nothing stopping you from instantiating multiple ImapClients and connecting them to the same IMAP server and credentials.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
1. I want all the emails saved as .eml file. How can I do that using GetStreams() or GetStreamsAsync()?
2. I have tried with 10 concurrent connections, but whenever I am exceeding 14-15 connections, I am getting login failed. From protcol logger also I am getting Login failed.

Comment: The streams are already in the correct format. Just write them to a FileStream. `using (var file = new FIle.Create ("something.eml")) { stream.CopyTo (file); }`

Comment: As far as getting errors when you try to make 14-15 concurrent connections, that's a server issue. Most servers have a max number of concurrent connections that they will accept. Honestly I'm surprised you managed to get to 14-15 before seeing this error ;-)